# Routing: RedirectToAction(string action)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetnuke

This question is about the latest DNN platform release: DNN 8.0.1.
I am trying to redirect to an action in my controller-classes, but I am not able to do it.

For example the following check:

`// Check if user is voting on his own item
    if (item.CreatedByUserId == User.UserID)
        return RedirectToAction("Index");`

This is the error I receive when the controller tries to return an action.
*DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: No route in the route table matches the supplied values. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: No route in the route table matches the supplied values.*

I don't know how routing is working in DNN (MVC) and I couldn't find anything helpful about is.

Thank you!

Comment: your `Settings` action method is in the same controller?

Comment: No, there is no action "Settings" in my controller. I was just trying a few values. But there is an index method, and it's not working with that method/action either.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the controller? RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller")?

Comment: @MarioGarcia Yes I did, not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DNN's routing is different from MVCs because it has to untangle different modules. You could create a method in your controller to override the default method in this way:

```
    public new ActionResult RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues)
    {
        var routeVals = TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionary(routeValues);
        routeVals["controller"] = controllerName;
        routeVals["action"] = actionName;
        return Redirect(ModuleRoutingProvider.Instance().GenerateUrl(routeVals, ModuleContext));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution worked.
But, I am still wondering if it is possible to register the routes in the route table. Do you know if this is possible, and if, how I can achieve this?

Comment: Why would DNN not override the default behavior of IController.RedirectToAction so that it performs correctly?